# Working on "using" statement in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

I want to properly dispose the SqlConnection object whenever i come out of the method. So im using the "using" statement as shown below.

```
public int Hello()
{
   using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
   {
      using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(Query,con))
      {
       try
       {
          con.Open();
          return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          throw ex;
       }
       finally
       {
          con.Close()
       }
      }
   }
}
```

Now, what i want to know is, Will the above code

1. Dispose the Connection properly when an **Exception** is occured in ExecuteNonQuery.
2. Make sure we will not get any ConnectionPool issues
3. Make sure the data is returned properly
4. If an exception occurs in SqlConnection will it dispose the object?

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what do you mean ConnectionPool issue? and exception occurs in SqlConnection?

Comment: When the website/application is used multiple times after sometime we will get this exception - "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached" - This is because the number of OpenConnections reached the maximum size of the pool. So we need to properly Close/dispose the connection which will avoid this issue.

Comment: All that `catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; }` achieves is to screw up the stack trace on the exception. You should *never* write such code.

Comment: So how we can manage the exception in those case?

Comment: In what way do you think that that `catch` block "manages" exceptions? If an exception is thrown within the `try` block, you catch it and then immediately rethrow it -  meaning that [some outer layer of your code needs to catch this exception and handle it - or your unhandled exception handler needs to deal with this exception]. Compare that to if you hadn't written that `catch` block - that means that [some outer layer ...  deal with this exception] The situation is entirely the same whether you've written that block or not. Except the stack trace was reset so you don't know where it camefrom

Comment: That was a good information. I believe if i write the same code without Try catch also it should dispose all the objects written in Using statement and the outer layer will manage the exceptions too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `try/catch` if you're just going to throw it, just change your code to this:

```
public int Hello()
{
    using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(Query,con))
        {
            con.Open();
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

and regardless of what happens, exception or not, the connection will get closed if it's open and disposed.

Answer (score 1):

> Dispose the Connection properly when an Exception is occured in ExecuteNonQuery.
>   Yes
>
> Make sure we will not get any ConnectionPool issues

i guess you mean connections would be properly relieved after executing query. if that is your question than You should not by using this approach.

> Make sure the data is returned properly

using has nothing to do with returning data

> If an exception occurs in SqlConnection will it dispose the object?

Yes

though you can rewrite your code as

```
using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))
   {
      using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(Query,con))
      {
       try
       {
          con.Open();
          return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          throw;
       }       
      }
   }
```

Comment: We use to get this exception if the connection is not properly closed in an application ie  "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached" This is why i asked about connection pool issues.

Comment: if you are using this approach then you are properly closing the connections and you should not get this issue again.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the using statement for sqlconnection.

using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(constring))

Better you use try,catch and finally block to close the connection. So even if exception occurs in try & catch the finally block will execute and close the connection if its open.

The reason behind this is, think of below situaion.

1. Create object of a class that handles all database operation
   e.g. `DBUtility objDB = new DBUtility()`

the above statement creates object of class and also initializes the sqlconnection variable from the constructor.

1. Now i am using the object objDB for executing multiple queries one by one. For this it should initialize the sqlconnection object only once and use it for its whole life (life obj objDB).
2. In your case the sqlconnection will be initialized as and when the method is called.
3. So simply init the connection once and open/close it for each of your operations. Your connection will automatically disposed by Garbage collector when objDB is disposed.